# How to make a custom init in SwiftUI to use parameters from separate file

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making a Contacts list application, and I am currently trying to make it so that when you click a contact in the list from `ContentView`, you get their id#, pass that id# to the `updateDetailed_Data` function in `ContactDetail`, and therefore see the page of the contact with the detailed view.

My issue is the actual passing of the variable `link_id` (this is the id#) from `cellView` to `updateDetailed_Data`. I've learned about using a custom init in `ContactDetail`, but with my limited and basic knowledge of SwiftUI I would just like some help and guidance in getting that done. (Or if there is another better way to do this)

Here is the code, `ContentView` deals with the actual list, and `ContactDetail` deals with the detailed contact information.

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ContactsList()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 20.0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContactsList: View {
    @StateObject var listData = getData()

    var body: some View {
        List(0..<listData.data.count, id: \.self) {i in
            NavigationLink(destination: ContactDetail()) {

                if i == self.listData.data.count - 1 {
                    cellView(data: self.listData.data[i], isLast: true, listData: self.listData)
                }
                else {
                    cellView(data: self.listData.data[i], isLast: false, listData: self.listData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct cellView: View {
    var data: Response.Contact
    var isLast: Bool
    @ObservedObject var listData: getData
    @State var link_id: String? = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            if self.isLast {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/[.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.listData.updateData()
                    }
                }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.link_id = String(data.id)
                    }
            }
            else {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/[.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.link_id = String(data.id)
                    }
                
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
    }
}

class getData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = [Response.Contact]()
    @Published var limit = 15
    @Published var skip = 0
    
    init() {
        updateData()
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        let url = "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts?skip=\(skip)&limit=\(limit)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                let oldData = self.data

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = oldData + json.data
                    self.limit += 15
                    self.skip += 15

                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                                            
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let updated_date: String
    }
    struct Pagination_Data: Codable {
        public let skip: Int
        public let limit: Int
        public let total: Int
    }
    public let data: [Contact]
    public let pagination: Pagination_Data
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case pagination = "pagination"
    }
}
```

ContactDetail:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContactDetail: View {

    @StateObject var detailedData = getData_Detailed()

    var body: some View {
        individualView(data: self.detailedData.data, detailedData: self.detailedData)
    }
}

struct individualView: View {
    var data: Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed
    @ObservedObject var detailedData: getData_Detailed
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Phone Number:")
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(data.phone_number)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Birthday:")
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(data.birthday)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Address:")
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(data.address)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Contact Last Updated:")
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Text(data.updated_date)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Contact Created:")
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Text(data.create_date)
            }
        }
    }
}

class getData_Detailed: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed(id: 1, first_name: "", last_name: "", birthday: "", phone_number: "", create_date: "", updated_date: "", address: "")
    
    init() {
        updateDetailed_Data(link_id: "1")
    }
    
    func updateDetailed_Data(link_id: String) {
        let url = "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts/\(link_id)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response_Detailed.self, from: data!)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = json.data
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                                            
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(String(describing: error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContactDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactDetail()
    }
}

struct Response_Detailed: Codable {
    struct Contact_Detailed: Codable, Identifiable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let birthday: String
        public let phone_number: String
        public let create_date: String
        public let updated_date: String
        public let address: String
    }
    public let data: Contact_Detailed
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}
```

Comment: This required some refactoring, I've created [a gist with the solution](https://gist.github.com/cedricbahirwe/6400149dd7482431c99baa191aae4426)

Comment: Same issue as before -- you're not passing the ID to `ContactDetail`, so there's no way you can event start to think about getting it to `getData_Detailed`. See if the comment above solves your issue. If not, try re-writing your code with the style suggestions that I made yesterday so it's easier to read, and then see if you can at least get the id passed to `ContactDetail`.

Comment: @cedricbahwire apple thinks it is [unsafe to create an observed object inside a view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several notes so you can see the changes and how to connect everything

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContactsListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ContactsList()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 20.0)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContactsList: View {
    @StateObject var listData = GetData()
    
    var body: some View {
        //Change the list to use the data vs the index
        VStack{
            List(listData.data, id: \.id) {i in
                NavigationLink(destination:
                                //Pass the initial value as a parameter
                               ContactDetail(link_id: "\(i.id)")) {
                    //Added Equatable to Response.Contact to verify if it is the last one
                    if i == self.listData.data.last {
                        CellView(data: i, isLast: true, listData: listData)
                    }
                    else {
                        CellView(data: i, isLast: false, listData: listData)
                    }
                }
            }
            if listData.isLoading {
                //The user should be notified that they are waiting for something to load
                VStack{
                    ProgressView()
                    Text("Loading...")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//struct and class should be uppercase
struct CellView: View {
    var data: Response.Contact
    var isLast: Bool
    @ObservedObject var listData: GetData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            if self.isLast {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0)
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.listData.incrementData()
                        }
                    }
                //No need for a tap gesture because you have the contant and the id
            }
            else {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0)
                
                //No need for a tap gesture because you have the contant and the id
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
    }
}
//struct and class should be uppercase
class GetData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = [Response.Contact]()
    @Published var limit = 15
    @Published var skip = 0
    //The user should be notified that they are waiting for something to load
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    init() {
        //Since you are calling this here no need to call it again unless something changes
        updateData()
    }
    func incrementData(){
        limit += 15
        skip += 15
        updateData()
    }
    func decrementData(){
        if skip != 0{
            limit -= 15
            skip -= 15
            updateData()
        }
    }
    func updateData() {
        
        isLoading = true
        let url = "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts?skip=\(skip)&limit=\(limit)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                //Notify user of error
                print(err!)
                self.isLoading = false
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                let oldData = self.data
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = oldData + json.data
                    
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                    self.isLoading = false
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                //Notify user of error
                print(error)
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}


struct Response: Codable {
    struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let updated_date: String
    }
    struct Pagination_Data: Codable {
        public let skip: Int
        public let limit: Int
        public let total: Int
    }
    public let data: [Contact]
    public let pagination: Pagination_Data
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case pagination = "pagination"
    }
}
struct ContactDetail: View {
    
    @StateObject var detailedData = GetData_Detailed()
    //Add link_id to View
    var link_id: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if !detailedData.isLoading{
                IndividualView(detailedData: detailedData)
            }else{
                //The user should be notified that they are waiting for something to load
                ProgressView()
                Text("Loading...")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            //When the View appears call the method to get the updated data
            detailedData.updateDetailed_Data(link_id: link_id)
        }
    }
}

struct IndividualView: View {
    //No need to pass the data use the ObservedObject
    // You want to observe it for changes
    @ObservedObject var detailedData: GetData_Detailed
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(detailedData.data.first_name + " " + detailedData.data.last_name)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Phone Number:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(detailedData.data.phone_number)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Birthday:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(detailedData.data.birthday)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Address:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.title2)
                Text(detailedData.data.address)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Contact Last Updated:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(detailedData.data.updated_date)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Contact Created:")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(detailedData.data.create_date)
            }
        }
    }
}
//struct and class should be uppercase
class GetData_Detailed: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed(id: 1, first_name: "", last_name: "", birthday: "", phone_number: "", create_date: "", updated_date: "", address: "")
    //The user should be notified that they are waiting for something to load
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    init() {
        //No need to default to 1 because onAppear will call this method with the correct id
        //updateDetailed_Data(link_id: "1")
    }
    
    func updateDetailed_Data(link_id: String) {
        isLoading = true
        let url = "https://flaskcontact-list-app.herokuapp.com/contacts/\(link_id)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                //Notify user of error
                print(err!)
                self.isLoading = false
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response_Detailed.self, from: data!)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = json.data
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                    self.isLoading = false
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                //Notify user of error
                print(error)
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContactDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactDetail(link_id: "1")
    }
}

struct Response_Detailed: Codable {
    struct Contact_Detailed: Codable, Identifiable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let birthday: String
        public let phone_number: String
        public let create_date: String
        public let updated_date: String
        public let address: String
    }
    public let data: Contact_Detailed
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}

struct ContactsListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactsListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I see what you've done and the comments are very helpful for me to learn.